# Babel package makes figure not show in PDF

Tags: texlive, babel, includegraphics

I have made a Latex document containing a single image in the body and compiled it with pdflatex (Tex Live 2019) on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. In the resulting PDF, I there is no image but the meaningless symbols ,ь, instead. Here is the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{passer.jpg}
  \caption{A sparrow}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Although the image doesn't appear in the PDF, there are no errors and warnings in the pdflatex output. However, the figure appears when I don't include the babel package. Also, the figure appears in the output when I add the [h] argument, but the issue comes back if I include two figures (in this case, the first figure is present but the second one is not).
I am working on a cyrillic document, so I need help in making figures appear correctly with babel package.

[image: The compilation result]

EDIT 1:
This is the compilation log when babel package is included:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test1.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2aenc.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t2aenc.dfu))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmr.fd))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./test1.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Overfull \vbox (10.0pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
(./test1.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information){/usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc
/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t2a.enc}</usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/
sfrm1000.pfb>
Output written on test1.pdf (1 page, 7430 bytes).
Transcript written on test1.log.
```

And this is the compilation log without babel package:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test1.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2aenc.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t2aenc.dfu))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmr.fd))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./test1.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} <./passer.jpg>]
(./test1.aux) ){/usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t2a.enc}</us
r/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb>
Output written on test1.pdf (1 page, 72668 bytes).
Transcript written on test1.log.
```

EDIT 2:
I have uploaded the logs and the image from the example to the Google drive. Here is the link:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/180QeQwz6L9FyM2aQXDQyNS_-_NopiaJ7?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Could you please provide the log of your compilation of this exact example? I have never seen `babel` affecting images before and since I do not have your example image, I'd like to see the log file, preferably with and without `babel`

Comment: Sure, I have added the outputs of pdflatex in the question. Or did you mean the content of log files?

Comment: you should show the complete log file. And make the jpg available somehow.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't add the contents of the log files in the post because of the limitations on the post size. The maximum post size is 30000 characters, and each of the logs contains more than 15000 characters.

Comment: May be unrelated, but `T2A` is a Cyrillic encoding. If your document is written in English you should not request it.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I am writing a Cyrillic document.

Comment: I added the link to Google Drive with the logs and the jpg.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Your log does shows an suspicious overful vbox, but no indication where it is from. But I'm on windows and my systems have different package versions than yours.

Comment: On the another machine with Ubuntu 18.04, I can't reproduce it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue disappeared after I installed TexLive 2021 directly from tug.org. Before, I tried to purge and reinstall Texlive from Ubuntu repository, but that didn't help.